# One argument of a C function getting lost

Tags: c, arguments, mex

I have a function that I took from a library that takes just two arguments, one integer and one pointer to something that is intended to be a matrix:

```
double *r8mat_expm1 ( int n, double *a );
```

I declare a variable to use, and allocate some memory for it:

```
double *matrix;
matrix = (double*)mxCalloc(1000,sizeof(double));
```

Then, I checked with print statements to make sure that it is filled as I intend before calling it, e.g.:

```
mexPrintf("First element of matrix is: %f\n", matrix[0]);
ans = r8mat_expm1(n, matrix);
```

Once inside the function,  the first thing I do is check that the arguments were passed properly:

```
double *r8mat_expm1 ( int n, double *a )
{ 
  mexPrintf("n is %d. First element of a is: %lf\n",n, a[0]);
 ...
```

And I learn from this print statement that `n` has been passed properly, but `a` has not! I cannot see how this is happening, given that no other lines of code are executed from the time I check on the contents of `matrix` until passing it to the function. For the sake of completeness, I also tried declaring and passing `matrix` as an array (i.e. `double a []`), but that didn't work, either...

Is there something that could be going on with this library function that makes the syntax I used in all of my homemade functions not work the same way?

UPDATE: When I moved the function r8mat_expm1() from a separate source file into the same source file as "main" (which is actually a mexFunction), the argument passing indeed went without a hitch -- good news for continuing my work, but now I am even more confused. Does that mean that there was a problem with the linking? If so, how could it happen that the integer argument was passed in that case, but the pointer to double argument failed?

Specifically, what would happen when the function was in the separate source code (as when originally posted) is that the matrix "a" would be filled not with random values, but completely with zeros, which is very fishy. (I added the tag 'mex' to the question, since I now suspect this is a Matlab/mex specific problem, and that in a regular C environment, everything may have been fine.)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Oh, note that this is C from within Matlab's "mex"-- hence the special printf statement. I don't know if this is relevant to my question, but I don't think it is.

Comment: What do you mean that `a` wasn't "properly passed". And please format your code. You can either indent it by four spaces, or wrap it in backticks.

Comment: Inside your function, you are using a different directive (`%lf`) to format the matrix element than you are using outside (`%f`).  The former is wrong, and the latter is correct.  (Note that this is one of the few areas where `printf()` and `scanf()` formatting directives differ.)

Comment: In C99 and later, `printf()` is required to treat `%f` and `%lf` the same.  In C90, `%lf` was undefined.

Comment: Your 'outside' print statement doesn't print `n`.  What is its type?  Please show an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: What does `mexPrintf` do?  Perhaps it contains some memory management bugs and is modifying things unintentionally.

Answer (score 2):

I have compiled and run your code as follows. It did not fail for me.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double *r8mat_expm1(int n, double *a);

int main()
{
    double *matrix;
    matrix = (double*)calloc(1000,sizeof(double));
    *matrix = 5.67;
    printf("First element of matrix is: %f\n", matrix[0]);
    int n = 27;
    double *ans = r8mat_expm1(n, matrix);
    return 0;
}

double *r8mat_expm1(int n, double *a)
{
    printf("n is %d. First element of a is: %lf\n", n, a[0]);
    return a;
}
```

The output was:

```
First element of matrix is: 5.670000
n is 27. First element of a is: 5.670000
```

Incidentally, @JohnBollinger is right: one should use the same `%f` specifier in both places.

Comment: Thanks for checking this! Your answer made me wonder whether I should just try moving r8mat_exmp() into the same source file as main-- see update above-- which fixed the problem. But should everything not have operated the same way if the function was in a file linked via #include "expm.h" which held r8mat_expm1()'s prototype?

Comment: Yes, it should. It should have operated the same way. Moreover, the reason it should have operated the same way is the reason you have given. If it is not operating the same way, this probably means that you have a *linking* problem rather than a *compilation* problem. Linking problems are irritating; they tend to be hard to diagnose and, once diagnosed, trivial to fix. Good luck.